# How to do WebView in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, jsx, html-rendering

I've tried different methods to render an html content from json response to react native.But I got failed in these methods

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-render-html
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-htmlview

Because there is no package that support `table` tag of `html`. So I thought to use WebView in react native.But that also disappointed me. There is no field to give `html content` from json response in `WebView`. I've tried the following.
But these are not working

**code**

```
<WebView
        source={{uri: `<h1>Hello World</h1>`}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
```

In my case I'm fetching server response.I've double checked whether response is coming ,the response from server is fine.

```
  return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
      <View>
      {this.state.section.map(article =>
      <View>

      <WebView
        source={{uri:article.data.description}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
      </View>

)}
        </View>

      </Container>
    );
```

Is there any other method for rendering html content other than these. Please I'm stuck with this.I don't know what to do.This cause delay in my project.So I'm really disappointed.Please any help would be really appreciable.

Comment: Please add some height and width to the `WebView` and then see if it appears ? I have had hard time knowing that WebView will be rendered only when you provide height and width to it. Also, `react-native-render-html` is pretty nice but it lags a lot of places. Try customizing it for your needs its really easy, the folks have written it good.

Comment: Yes I tried by giving `<WebView
        source={{html:article.data.description}}
        style={{flex: 1, height:200, width:200}}
      />`.But still I'm getting a blank page. But `react-native-render-html` doesn't support `table` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem.I was using `native-base` ui kit.So when I tried to render `WebView` within `Container` or `Content` it won't render.So I removed it with `View` component but `ScrollView` don't work.So I've made some changes to `Container` and it is working perfect.But still remains a problem that border of `html table` is not displaying.But otherwise it is perfect

This is my working code

```
<Content contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 ,padding:15}}>
   {this.state.section.map(article =>
      <WebView
      source={{ html: article.data.description}}
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
       />
       )}
    </Content>
```